# How to implement jQuery cookies on this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

I just wrote this code to use a slide to toggle a box as hidden/displayed using a button:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function () {
    jQuery('#box').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

I want to implement cookies on this to remember if the box was hidden or visible. Can someone guide me with this?

Comment: Google for "javascript cookies"

Comment: i want to use jquery cookies.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990299/implementing-jquery-cookie-plugin u might find it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a jQuery Cookie plugin available, which will make reading and writing to and from cookies a lot easier and more convenient. Here is an example:

```
// if the slider is visible, set the cookie slider value to true
$.cookie('slider', 'visible', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

To read the value, use the following as an example:

```
var sliderVisible = $.cookie('slider');
```

More information can be found on the [jQuery Cookies Plugin Site](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Answer (score 1):

I just got it working. I made two buttons so that there is different button on each state (i.e closed and open)

```
jQuery('#button_open').hide(); //initially we keep the open button hidden
```

// this code defines what happens when we click the close button

```
jQuery('#button_close').click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide(); //this hides the close button as the box is now closed
      jQuery('#box').slideUp('fast'); //hides the box
      jQuery('#button_open').show(); //shows the open button
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","closed", {expires: 365}); // sets cookie
      return false;
    });
```

// this code defines what happens when we click the open button

```
jQuery("#button_open").click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide(); //hides the open button as the box is now open
      jQuery('#box').slideDown('fast'); //shows the box
      jQuery('#button_close').show(); //shows the close button
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","open", {expires: 365}); //sets cookie
      return false;
    });
```

//and now the magical part comes in. this code checks if the cookie named 'openclose' has the value 'closed'. If yes, it hides the close button + the box and shows the open button.

```
    if(jQuery.cookie("openclose") == "closed") {
        jQuery("#button_close").hide();
        jQuery("#button_open").show();
        jQuery('#box').hide();
    };
```

Comment: Hi T, Congratulations on finding the answer. Nice documentation skills too! This is really clear and helpful. +1